# Have jquery datepicker fill 2 external fields

Tags: jquery, widget, field

I want to have a datepicker-button that inserts the selected date in text-fields. 
How can I achieve that?

Assume I have Button A, Textfield B, Textfield C. 
When you click on Button A, the jquery datepicker should open. Instead of filling the value inside the opened element, the same value shall be inserted into Textfield B and Textfield C.

Normally you would define what id has a datepicker attached to like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

But this logic doesn't work in this case, as the value shall be filled into different fields.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? Also please clarify what `colorpicker` has to do with issues and show the relevant html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here i have three textbox(datepicker, TextboxB, TextboxC) not as you asked( Button A, Textfield B, Textfield C). I dont think jQuery datepicker can display when you click a button instead, you make it a textbox. But one thing i did for you is this `"Instead of filling the value inside the opened element, the same value shall be inserted into Textfield B and Textfield C."`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker").change(function() {
      $("#textboxB, #textboxC").val($(this).val());
  });
  
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="click me"/>
<input type="text" id="textboxB" />
<input type="text" id="textboxC" />
```

Comment: If it's jQuery UI the datepicker can be bound to any element and then use events to do updates

Comment: if its possible then from the change function you can reference the element and the rest is ok

Comment: well not really... `change` is only valid on form controls

Comment: you can also use click function

Comment: click on what? datepicker API provides all the events needed

Comment: the click function that will do this for you $("#textboxB, #textboxC").val($(datepicker).val());

Comment: that won't integrate into the selection process though ... which is why you would use the widget API